# Does Nhibernate 3.0 QueryOver handle SQL injections properly?

Tags: nhibernate, hql, sql-injection

I know it's based off HQL so is it just using the same mechanisms that SetString, etc use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually QueryOver is a strongly typed representation of the Criteria API, not the HQL API. Regardless, it sanitizes parameters.